# How to verify ADFS encrypted SAML Response (Assertion)

Tags: python, saml, adfs

I am able to login and receving SAMLResponse through HTTP-Redirect binding and also I can able to decrypt using privatekey and able to retrive claims.

My question is still do we need to verify saml response(ADFS)? if its how to do that

do I need to use IP(identity provider) public key ? will it available in IP(Metadata)?

I have SAML response in the following request parameter

SAMLResponse = `base64(deflate(data))`
signature = hashvalue
sigAlg = sha256

how to validate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to also verify the digital signature of the SAML response. This is because the encryption is done using your public this is available to anyone that has access to your metadata and does not give any assurance that it was produces by your IdP.

To verify that you IdP is the one that produced the SAMLResponse you verify the digital signature of the SAMLResponse using the IdP public key. This is typically available in the IdP metadata.

Comment: I have SAML response in the following request parameter

SAMLResponse = base64(deflate(data))
signature = hashvalue
sigAlg = sha256

how to validate?

Comment: Depends on the software you are using. However you might run into some problems. HTTP Redirect is not allowed for delivering SAML response in web SSO. This is done using HTTP post or HTTP artifact bindings.

Comment: I have verified using python  publickey.verfier(base64(deflate(data)),signature) -> but it returns fail.